# Ruby File Handing, reading then storing as Array

Tags: ruby

I'm unable to understand how get this piece of code working, the program is able to read the file but ends up print the same line multiple times.

**Output:**

```
Track title is: c/music/1

Track file location is: c/music/1

Track title is: c/music/2 

Track file location is: c/music/2

Track title is: c/music/3

Track file location is: c/music/3
```

**Expected output:**

```
Track title is: Taco

Track file location is: c/music/1

Track title is: Burrito 

Track file location is: c/music/2

Track title is: Nacho

Track file location is: c/music/3
```

**Code:**

```
class Track
    attr_accessor :title, :file_location
end

def read_tracks music_file

    count = music_file.gets().to_i
  tracks = Array.new
  $i = 0

  while $i < count do
  track = read_track(music_file)
  tracks << track
  $i += 1
  end
    tracks
end


def read_track aFile

  track_title = aFile.gets
  track_file_location = aFile.gets
  track = Track.new
  track.title = track_title
  track.file_location = track_file_location

end



def print_tracks tracks
  $i = 0
  while $i < tracks.length do
    print_track(tracks)
    $i += 1
  end

end


def print_track tracks
  puts('Track title is: ' + tracks[$i].to_s)
    puts('Track file location is: ' + tracks[$i].to_s)
end


def main
  aFile = File.new("input.txt", "r") 
  if aFile  
    tracks = read_tracks(aFile)
    aFile.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to read!"
  end

  print_tracks(tracks)
end

main
```

**Sample of input file:**

```
5

Taco

c/music/1

Burrito

c/music/2

Nacho

c/music/3
```

Comment: in your input text file, can we assume that each track info is on a new line? Can you post a sample of input file? Also, can you post an formated example of output?  The way you have it, it looks like you want to output a single line of text with no new lines of text.

Comment: hello, sorry for the poor formatting of the post. The input file has 7 lines, the first line contains a number which indicates the number of 'tracks'. I am also wanting an output with new lines.

Comment: what does the 5 indicate in the first line of the input file?  Does this pattern repeat?  It's hard to understand what the pattern is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, coping lines to array, then manipulating it:

```
lines = File.readlines('tracks.txt') # reads lines into array
lines.reject! { |e| e == "\n" } # removes empti lines
total_tracks = lines.shift.chomp.to_i # extract the first line from the array
lines.each_slice(2) { |e| puts e } # lines now contains only the pair track/directory
# adapt at your will
```

For `each_slice(2)` see [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), it groups the elements of array in groups.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the methods **print_tracks** and **print_track**.
These methods should look like this:

```
def print_tracks tracks
  $i = 0
  while $i < tracks.length do
    print_track(tracks[$i])
    $i += 1
  end    
end


def print_track track
  puts('Track title is: ' + track.title.to_s)
    puts('Track file location is: ' + track.file_location.to_s)
end
```

But if you want to make your code better, try something like this:

```
def print_tracks(tracks)
  tracks.each do |track|
    puts "Track title is: #{track.title}"
    puts "Track file location is: #{track.file_location}"
    puts
  end
end
```

In this case whole code will be:

```
class Track
  attr_accessor :title, :file_location
end

def read_tracks music_file
  count = music_file.gets().to_i
  tracks = Array.new
  i = 0

  while i < count do
    track = read_track(music_file)
    tracks << track
    i += 1
  end

  tracks
end

def read_track aFile
  track = Track.new
  track.title = aFile.gets
  track.file_location = aFile.gets
  track
end

def print_tracks(tracks)
  tracks.each do |track|
    puts "Track title is: #{track.title}"
    puts "Track file location is: #{track.file_location}"
    puts
  end
end

def main
  aFile = File.new("input.txt", "r").
  if aFile..
    tracks = read_tracks(aFile)
    aFile.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to read!"
  end

  print_tracks(tracks)
end

main
```

I've tested this code using sample file input.txt:

```
3
Taco
c/music/1
Burrito
c/music/2
Nacho
c/music/3
```

I've got output:

```
Track title is: Taco
Track file location is: c/music/1

Track title is: Burrito
Track file location is: c/music/2

Track title is: Nacho
Track file location is: c/music/3
```

This is exactly what you expected!

Comment: Please, do not use global variables in Ruby (or anywhere else for that matter), ever.

Comment: Jörg W Mittag, when I posted solution, I tried make minimal changes to author's code, for easier understanding of code difference. Of course, global variables are not needed there.

Comment: Jörg W Mittag, I've added slightly improved version of code, just to show example of how it should be.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I'm still not getting the desired output. I believe the error lies in the reading of the file and especially when storing the read data as an array.

Comment: @Pickles, what is the output of your program with new revision of method print_tracks?

Comment: same as before, I believe the problem lies in read_track or read_tracks, or the line tracks << track. When pushing the tracks to array, it only pushes the 2nd attribute 'file_location' but if I change the order of title and file_location, it then pushes the title.

Comment: @Pickles, I've merged your and my code, tested it and added result to my post. Try it, it works!